# Moving item to front in constant time in Java

Tags: java

I need to implement two methods named MoveToFront and MoveToBack. These have to move the item to the front of the array and move the item to the back of the array. But the problem is that this has to be constant, meaning that the amount of items have no influence on the time of the methods.

I think this is impossible to do with an array in Java. So I have to use another data structure for it. I was thinking to implement it with a linkedList but this would only be constant if I had the index of the item.

Comment: Does the rest have to stay in order? If not, just swap the items.

Comment: It has to stay in order

Comment: Does the data structure need to support duplicate elements? Do MoveToFront and MoveToBack take an index or an element?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the structure of a linked list precludes the use of an index as you want it. If you say, "I want the data at index 5," you still have to traverse nodes 0-4 to get to index 5.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think it would have to be an index. If it were an element, we'd have to search the array for it first, and there isn't any constant-time search algorithm we could use to do this.

Comment: Now, a linked-list-ish structure could work if we were allowed to make MoveToFront and MoveToBack were pass-by-reference to the node. Is this allowed?

Comment: @HylianPikachu: An index wouldn't work. On the other hand, a manually-implemented linked list with a map from elements to nodes would work, if the move methods take an element and duplicate elements aren't allowed. (Python's [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) uses this strategy to manage element order, and supports this kind of element movement.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, so you use your map to get a reference to a node, at which point you can update both that node's connections and the first/last node's connections in constant time. Yowza. That's smart. I guess we just wait and see if the specs will allow it.

Answer (score -1):

In your question statement you say the problem is 'move to the front of the array'.  If it really means array, then you're right, it's not possible, because moving the array content is at least O(n), where 'n' is the position of the element to be removed.

If it's not an array, and you're allowed to choose the data structure, then fundamentally a linked-list is what you need.  How is the element to be moved identified? If by index, it's straightforward, as you observed.   Otherwise, keep a separate Map to allow O(1) lookup of the index for any element - assuming elements are unique.  Then it's a matter of

a. Look in map to get index

b. Remove index'ed entry from list

c. Replace entry in list at desired position

d. Fix up map entry

Comment: A linked list doesn't support constant-time element access by index.

Comment: The map could hold the node object rather than the index. This could be what @guest was trying to convey.

Comment: What (s)he's written is that step one is to look in the map to get the index, but agreed that this could work with some modification.

Comment: I'd delete the answer but it seems reputation is required.